# Error while trying to start media player: start called in state error (-38, 0)

Tags: android, gridview, media-player

I have a GridView with your positions and I do case on the *onCreate*, So,

> case position = 1 play audio1,
>
> case position = 2 play audio2

But when I execute, diplay a error and stop play sounds.

> start called in state error (-38, 0)

The Activity:

```
public class HomeEnglishFoodsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_english_foods);

GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridviewHomeEnglishFoods);
gridView.setAdapter(new AdapterHomeEnglishFoodsActivity(this));

final MediaPlayer mpApple = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.apple);
final MediaPlayer mpBeer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.beer);
final MediaPlayer mpCoffee = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.coffee);
final MediaPlayer mpCheese = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.cheese);
final MediaPlayer mpFrenchfries = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.frenchfries);
final MediaPlayer mpIcecream = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.icecream);
final MediaPlayer mpHotdog = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.hotdog);
final MediaPlayer mpWine = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.wine);

gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                            int position, long id) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                mpApple.start();
                break;
            case 1:
                mpBeer.start();
                break;
            case 2:
                mpCoffee.start();
                break;
            case 3:
                mpCheese.start();
                break;
            case 4:
                mpFrenchfries.start();
                break;
            case 5:
                mpIcecream.start();
                break;
            case 6:
                mpHotdog.start();
                break;
            case 7:
                mpWine.start();
                break;
        }

    }
});
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home_english_foods, menu);
return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
// automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
// as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
int id = item.getItemId();

//noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
    return true;
}

return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Error:

```
06-04 00:46:21.334  17752-17752/br.gabrielrossetto.tap4learn E/MediaPlayer﹕    Error (-19,0)
06-04 00:46:29.612  17752-17752/br.gabrielrossetto.tap4learn E/MediaPlayer﹕ start called in state 0
06-04 00:46:29.612  17752-17752/br.gabrielrossetto.tap4learn E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
06-04 00:46:29.652  17752-17752/br.gabrielrossetto.tap4learn E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (-38,0)
```

Comment: Did you check these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888510/mediaplayer-error-19-0-after-repeated-plays   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16172496/mediaplayer-error-19-0-doesnt-work-with-release

Comment: I use release but dont play the audio. Just play with start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error usually means you are trying to call a function while in wrong state, for example calling seek while media player not ready yet.
Try to add `mpApple.setOnPreparedListener()` listener then called `start()` once it is prepared, also you will need to release the player once you are done as they recommend in documentation, so I suggest you make one `MediaPlayer` instance, and stop + release it before using it to play new audio file. for example

```
 public class HomeEnglishFoodsActivity extends ActionBarActivity
 {
       MediaPlayer player;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
{
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View int position, long id) {
                switch (position)
                {
                    case 0:
                        if(player1 !=null)
                        {
                            player1.stop();
                            player1.release();
                        }
                        player1.create(this, R.raw.apple).setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer)
                            {
                                mediaPlayer.start();
                            }
                        });
                }
            }
        });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you stop the mediaPlayer it gives error because start mediaPlayer continue and you further start. your solution is you stop media then start again it works.

Comment: I add stop like this "case 1: mpBeer.stop(); mpBeer.start(); break;" but when i run dont play any sound.

Answer (score 0):

> try like this..

```
 switch (position) {
 case 0:

    if (mp != null)
    mp.release(); 
     mpApple.start();
    break;
    }
```